# Selecting maximum number value from a range and autofill down

Tags: vba, excel

I want VBA to select the maximum value from range (U2:VN2) and paste the value into range VO2
Then to autofill down column VO, so column VO would display the maximum value for each row down to last row with values.

I tried the following

```
Sub MaxValueAutofill()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim rX As Excel.Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lngMax As Double

Set r = Range("U2:VN2")
lngMax = Application.Max(r)
Set rX = r.Find(What:=lngMax, After:=Range("U2"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,    
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)     

If Not rX Is Nothing Then
    Application.Goto rX, Scroll:=True
End If
Selection.Copy
Range("VO2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("VO2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("VO2:VO" & lastRow)

End Sub
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
Sub Test()

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("VO" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("U2:VN2"))
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question stating "maximum value for each row", it doesn't sound like you want to just copy the maximum from row 2 into every row of column VO, so autofilling a *value* all the way down the column is not appropriate.  You actually need to autofill the "Max" *formula* all the way down and then convert to values.

```
Sub MaxValueAutofill()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("VO2:VO" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
             .Formula = "=MAX(U2:VN2)"
             .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Simple and yet efficient. Good job!